# spring.profiles.include does not work from command line parameter

Tags: spring-boot

I made trivial Spring Boot application and packaged it as JAR.
When I call

```
java  -jar target/boot-active-include-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I got

> No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

When I call

```
echo spring.profiles.include=B > application.properties 
java  -jar  target/boot-active-include-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I got

> The following profiles are active: B

When I call

```
rm application.properties
java -Dspring.profiles.include=B -jar target/boot-active-include-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I got

> No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

But I expect  The following profiles are active: B

Can I include Spring profile from command line?

Version: 1.5.1.RELEASE

PS. `spring.profiles.active` works as expected. But I don't want replace active profiles.

Comment: Are you sure you are using 1.5.1? This should work thanks to this change: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/393cfe505e20496dc69b54aa94ba944dcdb75f0f. Another thing to double-check is that you are passing your main methods args array into your `SpringApplication`

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I'm sure, see https://github.com/michaldo/so-issue1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what's happening now, and I think it's arguably something I missed when making [this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/393cfe505e20496dc69b54aa94ba944dcdb75f0f).

Prior to that change, `spring.profiles.include` was only considered when it was used in a configuration file. Following that change, `spring.profiles.include` is now considered from any source (System properties, command line arguments, etc) as long as `spring.profiles.active` is also set.

You can see this by running your sample with both properties set:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.include=alpha -Dspring.profiles.active=bravo -jar target/boot-active-include-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Both the `alpha` and `bravo` profiles are active:

```
2017-02-09 11:30:49.467  INFO 40409 --- [           main] my.Example                               : The following profiles are active: alpha,bravo
```

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8244) so that we can straighten this out.